# Design on ALU in multisim

Tags: multisim, alu

I am trying to design a simple 2 bit ALU which can perform addition, OR and XOR. Here's the picture of my design in multisim.
[image: Picture of disign]

Problem with my design is i'm not understanding the purpose of select lines here. I refereed my note for that. I've something like below for arithmetic circuit design, concerning my note

[image]

I'm not sure whether i applied those strategy or not.

Answer (score 1):

The two select lines `S0` and `S1` will simply tell the two multiplexers which input to connect to the output. Observe that every function(Addition, AND, OR, and XOR) is connected to one of the four multiplexer inputs. Your ALU will always execute all four operations, but the setting of the select lines will actually decide which result the ALU will output.

Also, it seems there is a small error in your ModelSim design: the output signal of the `OR1` gate is supposed to connect to `D2` input of `MUX1`, but you have drawn them over the `D0` and `D1` inputs too; this could be a short circuit, make sure the `OR1` output is only connected to the `D2` input.